# formatting an array of objects output

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that I'm trying to get the output to display properly after using a filter and reduce.

It's outputting the data properly but not in the format I would like. Any input is much appreciated.

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

```
{
 5: 12,
 6: 15,
 7: 12,
 ...
}
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
{
 session5-count: 12,
 session6-count: 15,
 session7-count: 12,
 ...
}
```

I'm sure this is something very simple and I haven't had lunch so could be blocking my thought process.

here is my formula and sample data

**UPDATED FUNCTION**

Thanks to **alex-g** & **zfrisch**

```js
const sessionsArray = [
    { session: '5', status: 'inactive' },
    { session: '5', status: 'inactive' },
    { session: '5', status: 'inactive' },
    { session: '5', status: 'active' },
    { session: '5', status: 'active' },
    { session: '5', status: 'active' },
    { session: '5', status: 'active' },
    { session: '5', status: 'active' },
    { session: '5', status: 'active' },
    { session: '5', status: 'active' },
    { session: '5', status: 'active' },
    { session: '5', status: 'active' },
    { session: '6', status: 'active' },
    { session: '6', status: 'active' },
    { session: '7', status: 'inactive' },
    { session: '7', status: 'inactive' },
    { session: '7', status: 'inactive' },
    ];

const filteredSessions  = sessionsArray
    .reduce( (acc, {session, status}) => {

        if(status != 'active'){
           acc["session-" + session ] = 0
        }else{           
            acc["session-" + session ] =
            acc["session-" + session ] + 1 || 1
        } 
        
        return acc
    }, {}) 

console.log(filteredSessions )
```

I'm trying to follow along and use [THIS S.O. ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39660315/iterate-through-an-array-of-objects-and-output-custom-object) to help format my output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use template strings to get the desired key format. Like this:

```js
const sessionsArray = [
{ session: '5', status: 'inactive' },
{ session: '5', status: 'inactive' },
{ session: '5', status: 'inactive' },
{ session: '5', status: 'active' },
{ session: '5', status: 'active' },
{ session: '5', status: 'active' },
{ session: '5', status: 'active' },
{ session: '5', status: 'active' },
{ session: '5', status: 'active' },
{ session: '5', status: 'active' },
{ session: '5', status: 'active' },
{ session: '5', status: 'active' },
{ session: '6', status: 'active' },
{ session: '6', status: 'active' },
{ session: '7', status: 'inactive' },
{ session: '7', status: 'active' },
{ session: '7', status: 'active' },
];

const filteredSessions = sessionsArray
    .filter(workshop => workshop.status === 'active')
    .reduce( (acc, { session }) => {
        
        acc[`session${session}-count`] = acc[`session${session}-count`] + 1 || 1;
        
        return acc;
    }, {});

console.log(filteredSessions)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed!

Comment: as an aside, you can use destructuring to just grab the one property you need. A.e. `.reduce((acc, {session}) =>`

Comment: Thats true @zfrisch . Thinking about this now. This does not account for if a session has all entries as 'inactive'. If I remove the filter function. Can I add a condition to return 0 within the reduce function?

Comment: @cpt-crunchy `.reduce(acc, {session, status}) => { 
if(status != "active") return acc;`

Comment: I was just testing that out. Thanks @zfrisch